# Login to site while using proxy

Tags: html, forms, cookies, authentication, proxy

So I am using php to retrieve page HTML from URL with `file_get_contents`. The site loads fine and everything, but the login field wont work. Anyway to login while using this method?

Dont know it it helps, but here is the login form.

```
<form class="login-panel async-form" method="post">    
        <div class="yui3-g">
            <label class="email yui3-u-1-2">
                <input
                    type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""
                    placeholder="E-mail &#x2F; Account Name" autofocus required />
            </label>

            <label class="password yui3-u-1-2">
                <input
                    type="password" id="password" name="password" value=""
                    placeholder="Password" required />
            </label>
            <br />

            <a class="login-reset yui3-u" href="https://yummmmmm-c9-veloncia.c9.io/plawy.php?id=&#x2F;recovery">
                Forgot your password?
            </a>



            <button type="submit" class="yui3-button yui3-u">
                Sign in
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem seems a little unclear, but understandable. When using php to retrieve proxy data use `CURL` than `file_get_contents`:

```
      $url        = "http://randomplacedd.com/url-to-post-data-to";
$postfields = "var1=data&var2=data";
$password   = "password"

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $password);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

That way your proxy will retrieve the data

**Note:** If you wanted though you could change all the `CURL` to `file_get_contents`, but I strongly suggest using CURL